# how to execute the command with markdown with python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am making a bot using Python-telegram-bot library.

I'm looking for a way to execute the command with markdown.
For example, if I click on certain text in the message, I want to make certain commands run.
The command executed like that sends a new message to me.

Like this, I want to send message 'hi'.

```
message = '[hi](/help)'
```

if click 'hi', then I want to run command /help.

Is it possible? OR Is there any other good way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Others may be able to help you better if you can include example code of what you are trying to accomplish and what you expect the result to be. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional guidance.

Comment: did you find a solution?